# check if two integers sum to a third

Tags: java, math

Ok I'm doing this programming assignment and need a little help.

Here is the problem:

Given three ints, a b c, return true if it is possible to add two of the ints to get the third.

```
twoAsOne(1, 2, 3) → true
twoAsOne(3, 1, 2) → true
twoAsOne(3, 2, 2) → false
```

Here's the what I have gotten so far:

```
public boolean twoAsOne(int a, int b, int c) {
  return a + b != c;
}
```

It keeps saying it is not fully correct and I do not know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Major part of programming is understanding the requirements, and although the code is trivial to write, it is pretty clear that you need to understand the requirements. See the other comment I made on itowlson's response.

Answer (score 11):

The question asks if it is possible to add *any* two to get the remaining one.  Your code tests only if the *first two* add to the *third*.

Thus, twoAsOne(3,1,2) should return true because 3 = 1 + 2; but you are only checking whether 3 + 1 = 2, which is false.

Comment: @erics2008: it is YOUR job to write the code.  If you don't engage your brain to work it out for yourself, you won't learn anything from this homework exercise.  And learning is THE POINT of the exercise!

Comment: What Stephen said - I've given you an example of another combination that you need to check, but since this is homework, you're going to get more value out of it by figuring out the code yourself.  You've obviously figured out how to do one of the cases: consider what are the other cases and how might you handle those?

Comment: Think about the math. What's the property that the sum has in relation to the addends?

Answer (score 7):

You're only checking *one* of the possibilities *and*, on top of that, you're checking it wrongly since you'll return false if a + b == c (because you're using the `!=` operator).

I'm not going to do you homework for you, but the full list of possibilities is:

```
n1 = n2 + n3
n2 = n1 + n3
n3 = n1 + n2
```

It should be a simple matter: the result should be true if *any* of those is true. Otherwise the result should be false.

Or, to provide even a more obvious clue: it should be *true* *if* one *or* more of those conditions are met. *Else* it should be *false*.

I don't know how much more obvious I can make it without writing the code for you :-)

*Update:* And now that more than enough time has probably elapsed to make the homework point moot, here's my solution:

```
public boolean twoAsOne (int n1, int n2, int n3) {
    if (n1 == n2 + n3) return true;
    if (n2 == n1 + n3) return true;
    if (n3 == n1 + n2) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Although those last two lines could be replaced with:

```
    return (n3 == n1 + n2);
```

I prefer the (to me, anyway) more readable version.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the answers provided by itowlson and Pax, since you are dealing with ints, there is a possibility that they will overflow, e.g.

Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE

Which is not mathematically true

You may want to check this kind of scenarios to make your program complete.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only takes into consideration the sum of int a and int b. The solution requires all possibilities to be covered i.e. "sum of int a and int c" and "sum of int b and int c". Refer to the code mentioned below, hope it helps!

```
public boolean twoAsOne(int a, int b, int c) {
  return ((a + b == c) || (b + c == a) || (c + a == b));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude I hope you got the answer by now... if you haven't

```
public boolean twoAsOne(int a, int b, int c) {
    return ((a+b==c) || (a+c==b) || (b+c==a));
}
```

Comment: @Richie, it's considered "bad form" to just give the answers to homework questions. Not that I'll waste a downvote since (1) you're new here and (2) you can't go negative on rep :-)

Answer (score 0):

I might be very late yet I have minimized it. twoAsOne

```
public boolean twoAsOne(integer a, integer b, integer c){
    return ((a+b) == c ? true : (a+c) == b ? true : (b+c == a)? true : false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package get_third;

public class Get_third {
    int a , b ,c ;
    boolean third_value(int a , int b , int c){

    if(a+b==c||b+c==a||c+a==b)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Get_third obj =new Get_third();
        System.out.println(obj.third_value(1, 2, 3));
        System.out.println(obj.third_value(3, 1, 2));
        System.out.println(obj.third_value(3, 2, 2));      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// start

```
public boolean twoAsOne(int a, int b, int c) {

    if (a + b == c) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (a + c == b) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (b + c == a) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

// end

Comment: It does seem likely that the OP got their answer within the last 10 years.

Comment: Hopefully, this will help.
PS. I am sure he's probably a senior programmer by now